# Can videos within an iframe be controlled by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I already know that YouTube videos can be stopped and started by JavaScript commands that Google provides.  I know that Vimeo videos can be stopped and started by Javascript commands that Vimeo provides.

The videos of both are within 'iframes'.

My question is - did you have a video or sound-file in an iframe that is not from either company?  Is there a way, for instance, to know if the user has clicked on the pause icon?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends if the iframe is cross domain or not. Not enough details provided about specifics of iframe or videos. See: [ask]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes. The answer to your question is yes it is possible to know if user has clicked the pause button.

But this may not be correct unless you describe the complete context. For example HTML5 audio video players, have events invoking where you can tap what goes on with them. So e.g. they have 'pause' event fired when user clicks the pause button.

Also it depends on from where the media, infact the page in iframe is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Because of XSS protections,  Cross site contents can not be accessed by javascript. You could however, load the iframe url with a *proxy* script in your server.